# Finding the coefficients of the Weirestrass $\wp$ function.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am trying to find the coefficients of the $\wp$-function.

Right now I have the Laurent series about the pole $ z = 0$:

$$\wp(z) = \frac{c_{-n}}{z^n} + \cdots + \frac{c_{-1}}{z} + c_0 + c_1 z + \cdots$$ where $c_{-n} \neq 0$

I know $n \geq 1$, and that $\wp$ satisfies

$$\left(\frac{d\wp(z)}{dz}\right)^2 = 4(\wp)(z))^3 -g_2 \wp(z) -g_3$$

I know the end form I am looking form is the well known equation:

$$\wp(z) = z^{-2} +b_0 +b_1 z^2 +b_2 z^4+\cdots $$

But I am not sure how to show that $n = 2$ and that $c_{-n} = 1$.

I know  I can substitute the Laurent Series into the differential equation, but that isn't helping me, at least not with my algebra skills.

Comment: can anyone help?